# Specify colors above and below median on violin plot in Seaborn / Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am generating violin plots and would like to display a line at the median of the distribution, with different colors for the areas above and below the median. Here is a MVCE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

np.random.seed(1)
d1 = np.random.normal(size=5000)
d2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=5000)

x = d1 + d2

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
seaborn.violinplot(y=x)
```

Here is the resulting plot:

[image]

and the output I'd like to create:

[image]

I've searched for a while now and cannot seem to find any documentation or examples for doing this. Can it be done in matplotlib or seaborn (or any other plotting library in Python)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not fully happy with the results, but here is my stab at it.

I'm using `matplotlib` version of `violinplot()` instead of `seaborn`'s because the former returns a dictionary with the various Artists that were produced, although the same could be done with seaborn with a bit more effort to locate the proper `Collection` object.

The violin plot is actually drawn using a `PolyCollection`, from which the coordinates of the vertices can be extracted. With those in hands, it is simply a matter of selecting the coordinates that are either above or below the median, and create a new `PolyCollection` to add to the axes. Finally, I delete the original artist.

I'm not fully satisfied with the result because the two artists thus created don't touch. This is because we're missing the vertices originally connecting the bottom part to the top part. If that's a problem for you, this could probably be fixed by adding new coordinates at the beginning and end of either one of the collection vertice coordinates that match the ones from the other collection, thus filling the gap.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()


np.random.seed(1)
d1 = np.random.normal(size=5000)
d2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=5000)

x = d1 + d2
mdn = np.median(x)

# draw the violinplot using matplotlib, storing the resulting dictionnary of artists
result_dict = ax.violinplot(x, showextrema=False, showmedians=True)

orig_violin = result_dict['bodies'][0]  # in this case, there is only one violin plot, hence [0]
orig_vertices = orig_violin.get_paths()[0].vertices # extract the vertices coordinates from the Path object contained in the PolyCollection

top = orig_vertices[orig_vertices[:,1]>=mdn]   # the vertices above the median
bottom = orig_vertices[orig_vertices[:,1]<mdn] # and below 

# create new PolyCollections, adjusting their appearance as desired
topP = matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection([top])
topP.set_facecolor('C1')
bottomP = matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection([bottom])
bottomP.set_facecolor('C2')

ax.add_collection(topP)
ax.add_collection(bottomP)

# remove the original(s) artists created by matplotlib's violinplot()
[temp.remove() for temp in result_dict['bodies']]
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I came up with about the same solution, just a bit too late. Since there are still some minor differences, I though it to be useful to post anyways. @Fiver If in doubt, this is probably the solution to accept, because mine just came later and only brings marginal improvement.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you both. As I suspected there seems no direct way to do this in seaborn. I think I'll leave the question open a bit longer and maybe put up a bounty to see if I get any other ideas. Thanks again.

Comment: What would be a reason to "do this in seaborn"? Seaborn is merely a wrapper for matplotlib. What other ideas are you looking for?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sorry, I didn't mean to imply it had to be done in seaborn. I had changed to seaborn because it looked a little nicer and was more convenient; also, I wanted to retain the box plot. Both your posts have been very helpful in showing how to tinker with the inner workings of the plots.

Answer (score 1):

I already had a solution ready but now see that @DizietAsahi has posted a similar solution. I will still post it here, and only point at the differences.

Usually you would like to have several violins. So it's good to put everything in a loop. That loop can live in a function. And the function can directly be used to style the violins. Now, I would in contrast to the existing solution, create two violin plots and from each one cut either the upper or lower part. This could then look like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
d1 = np.random.normal(size=5000)
d2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=5000)

x = [d1+1, d1 + d2, d2-0.5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
violin1 = ax.violinplot(x, showmedians=True, showextrema=False, points=300)
violin2 = ax.violinplot(x, showmedians=True, showextrema=False, points=300)

def cut_violin_at_median(violin, cut_above=True, **kwargs):
    for i in range(len(violin["bodies"])):
        median = violin["cmedians"].get_paths()[i].vertices[0,1]
        pthcol = violin["bodies"][i]
        v = pthcol.get_paths()[0].vertices
        if cut_above:
            ind = v[:,1] <= median
        else:
            ind = v[:,1] > median
        pthcol.set_verts([v[ind]])
        pthcol.set(**kwargs)

cut_violin_at_median(violin1, cut_above=True, color="crimson")
cut_violin_at_median(violin2, cut_above=False, color="limegreen")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that in order to not have a huge gap in between the two parts of the violin, you may increase the number of points at which the kernel density estimate is performed. Here, I use 300, but maybe even higher numbers are useful.